# Select inside a select query (lists)

Tags: c#, linq, select

I have this code:

```
HashSet<string> MyHash = new HashSet<String>();

foreach (MyType a in myCollection)
{
    foreach (string b in a.mylist)
    {
        MyHash.Add(b);
    }
}
```

I tried to make it easier to read like this but it doesn't work:

```
myCollection.MyType.select(x => x.mylist.select(y => MyHash.add(y)));
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Please define "doesn't work". As it stands it looks like you'd have quite a few compiler errors on your hands.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Select` will *return* a collection of items instead of *modifying* it. Thus you have to assign its return-value into a variable or member or pass it into a method. Furthermore you´d need to flatten the results to add the members of your inner list into the hashset.

Thus when you want to add the result into your list use `HashSet.UnionWith`:

```
myHash.UnionWith(myCollection.SelectMany(x => x.MyList));
```

Alternativly you can also use the constructor of `HashSet` that accepts a collection of items:

```
var myHash = new HashSet<string>(...);
```

However IMHO this isn´t any more readable than using some foreach-based approach.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how I would do it, separating query definition and state modification.

```
IEnumerable<string> items = myCollection.SelectMany(a => a.myList);

foreach(string b in items)
{
  MyHash.Add(b);
}
```

---

If you want to one-line it for some reason:

```
myCollection.SelectMany(a => a.myList).ToList().ForEach(b => MyHash.Add(b));
```